# How to make an infinite ticker line with only one image?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have it almost working as expected. However, since there is only one image, when animates to the left side, a gap opens up on the right side. What I need is that the ticker line would always be filled in with the same image, without any gaps.
If image is narrower than the container, it should repeat to left and right.

Any help or guidance is much appreciated.

```js
const tickerImage = document.getElementById('ticker-image');
const tickerLink = document.getElementById('ticker-link');

let isRotating = true;

tickerLink.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  if (isRotating) {
    e.preventDefault(); // Prevent the link from navigating if it's rotating
  }
});

tickerLink.addEventListener('mouseover', function() {
  isRotating = false;
  tickerImage.style.animationPlayState = 'paused';
});

tickerLink.addEventListener('mouseout', function() {
  isRotating = true;
  tickerImage.style.animationPlayState = 'running';
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.ticker {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #333;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px 0;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  user-select: none;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.ticker-content {
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  /* Set the width to 100% */
  height: 100%;
  /* Set the height to 100% */
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.image-container {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  animation: slideImage 10s linear infinite;
}

.image-container img {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%
}

@keyframes slideImage {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(100%);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(-100%);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="ticker">
  <a href="https://example.com" target="_blank" class="ticker-content" id="ticker-link">
    <div class="image-container">
      <img src="https://images.all-free-download.com/images/graphiclarge/beach_cloud_dawn_horizon_horizontal_landscape_ocean_601821.jpg" alt="Rotating Image" id="ticker-image">
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

background-size: cover; you can try this property in the .tickercontent

Comment: It doesn't seem to change anything, there is still an empty gap on the right side once the image animates to the left side.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```css
      * {
        overflow: hidden;
      }
      .test {
        display: flex;
        background-image: url("https://images.all-free-download.com/images/graphiclarge/beach_cloud_dawn_horizon_horizontal_landscape_ocean_601821.jpg");
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: contain;
      }
      #ticker-image {
        width: 100%;
        animation: slideImage 10s linear infinite;
      }
      @keyframes slideImage {
        0% {
          transform: translateX(100%);
        }
        100% {
          transform: translateX(-100%);
        }
      }
```

```html
<div class="test">
<img
        src="https://images.all-free-download.com/images/graphiclarge/beach_cloud_dawn_horizon_horizontal_landscape_ocean_601821.jpg"
        alt="Rotating Image"
        id="ticker-image"
      />
    </div>
```

Comment: Almost there, but the problem with your suggestion is that it stretches the image to take full screen width. If the image is f.ex. 600px in width, and the screen is 2000px, the image would then take the whole width, instead of being displayed 3.2 times on that wide screen.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).